# Get the post of a logged-in user

Tags: php, sql

This query gets the post of a logged-in user's friend, I need to get his own post.

Friend table is 3 col, id | user_one | user_two

```
    $get_tablepost = "select * FROM post 
    INNER JOIN friend ON post.user_id = friend.user_one && friend.user_two = 
    '$UserLoggedIn' || post.user_user_id = friend.user_two && friend.user_one 
    ='$UserLoggedIn'
```

Comment: I need to include the post of users who is logged-in.

Answer (score -1):

I just add post.`user_id = '$UserLoggedIN';` and `GROUP BY` to avoid repetition and it works, but I don't know ,if it is the best solution^^.